# S3AsyncClient does not work with LocalStack when putting object

Tags: kotlin, amazon-s3, reactive-programming, localstack

When I try to put object in S3 using S3AsyncClient I get `Data read has a different checksum than expected`.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `verify data read has a different checksum than expected`() {
        val client = S3AsyncClient.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:4572"))
            .build()
        val data = Flux.fromIterable(listOf(ByteBuffer.wrap("test".toByteArray())))
        client.putObject(
            { it.bucket("test").key("test")},
            AsyncRequestBody.fromPublisher(data),
        ).get()
    }
```

I noticed https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/4597 but it does not provide any resolution nor workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the data is readable at this point?

Comment: It turns out that LocalStack requires `AsyncRequestBody` to have content length set - as in answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75790185/296427