# Download a file using Spring WebClient and store it on S3 using S3AsyncClient

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I want to download a file using WebClient and put it on S3.

The problem I face is that I need to have a "Content-Lenght" value in order to pass it to S3.

I can get it from `WebClient`, but I need to pass it to `AsyncRequestBody`, and I don't know how to store it alongside `Flux`:

```kotlin
val byteBuffers: Flux<ByteBuffer> = webclient
    .get()
    .uri(fileUrl)
    .exchangeToFlux {

        it.bodyToFlux<ByteBuffer>()
            .contextWrite { ctx ->
            ctx.put(
                "content-length",
                it.headers().contentLength()
            )
        }
    }

val asyncRequestBody = object : AsyncRequestBody {
    override fun subscribe(s: Subscriber<in ByteBuffer>) {
        byteBuffers.subscribe(s)
    }

    override fun contentLength(): Optional<Long> {
        // how to read Content-Length here?
    }
}

return s3Client.putObject(
    /* putObjectRequest = */ PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .key(fileKey)
        .bucket(s3bucket).build(),
    /* requestBody = */ asyncRequestBody
).toMono()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had to inline S3 calls into `.exchangeToMono`:

```kotlin
return webclient
    .get()
    .uri(fileUrl)
    .exchangeToMono {
        s3Client.putObject(
            PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .key(fileKey)
                .bucket(s3bucket).build(),
            object : AsyncRequestBody {
                override fun subscribe(s: Subscriber<in ByteBuffer>) {
                    it.bodyToFlux<ByteBuffer>().subscribe(s)
                }

                override fun contentLength(): Optional<Long> {
                    return Optional.of(it.headers().contentLength().asLong)
                }
            }
        ).toMono()
    }
```